# Cooperation, how to use it in a question?

Tags: questions

Is it correct to say:

`Would you like to start a cooperation (with us)?`

Or should it be: `Would you like to cooperate (with us)?`

I feel like the first sentence is wrong, as it sounds to much like saying `would you like to start a corporation (with us)?` (with a dutch accent) but the second sentence suggests more aggressive style of asking for someone to cooperate with you. Maybe there is a better way to ask this question?

**edit**

I should also state I am referring to a international business venture / collaboration. Where for example we would like to sell electronics on our website from his/her company for a small commission or put your vacation house up for rent on our website for a small commission. You would eventually sign a contact to do this(of course).

So what I'm asking is: is it correct to ask the above stated questions? or is there a better way?

Note: It should not sound like you would want to 'hook up' with the person your talking to e.g. partnering relationship

Comment: Are you referring specifically to a business venture / collaboration, or to some other kind of cooperation?

Comment: @ErikKowal Yes I'm referring to a business collaboration. Like offering their stuff on your website.

Comment: I tried to improve the question and incorporate these comments, but I ended up answering the question with ***collaboration*** and/or ***partnership*** so those words [and their verbs] might fit.

Comment: So is it better to ask `Would you like to start a collaboration/partnership (with us)?`? And is it incorrect to say `Would you like to start a cooperation (with us)?`?

Comment: @Arazu, if you have answered the question yourself, post your own answer and accept it, so anyone else looking at the question will have the correct answer.

Comment: @Arazu, the phrase `Would you like to start a cooperation (with us)` is ungrammatical, and should not be used.  The first option of `collaboration/partnership` is better.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I did not know the answer to my own question. I like the way jwpat7 explained it. That's why I accepted it as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct to say:
>
> > Would you like to start a cooperation (with us)?

Because the noun *[cooperation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cooperation#Noun)* has a sense “The act of cooperating or being cooperative” (wik.), one can re-form the above line as  “Would you like to start an act of cooperating or being cooperative with us?”  Such a question is grammatical and is semantically sound; that is, is not “incorrect”.  However, both forms are clumsy and unnatural.

One might instead say “Would you like to start a *cooperative venture*?” or (more naturally) “Would you like to enter into a cooperative venture?” or “Would you like to enter into a *joint venture*?”.

Note, [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=partnering+relationship%2Ccooperative+venture&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartnering%20relationship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccooperative%20venture%3B%2Cc0) for *partnering relationship,cooperative venture* shows that *partnering relationship* is a parvenu, not on the charts before 1980, and only about 2% as common much of the time since then.  However, *partnering relationship* seems to be on the rise, and *cooperative venture* on the decline.

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=partnering+relationship%2Ccooperative+venture%2Cjoint+venture&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartnering%20relationship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccooperative%20venture%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjoint%20venture%3B%2Cc0) for *partnering relationship,cooperative venture,joint venture* shows *joint venture* occurring typically about 30 times more frequently than *cooperative venture* and hundreds of times more frequently than *partnering relationship*.

From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/joint_venture), *joint venture* means “A cooperative partnership between two individuals or businesses in which profits and risks are shared”.  A wikipedia [joint venture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_venture) article mentions related terms and points out some distinctions among different kinds of partnerships.

Comment: I will upvote it when I can, but my reputation does not allow it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You have described a **partnering relationship.**  The business partners cooperate in a limited fashion.  For example, computer manufacturers may advertise *processors by Intel.*

Intel Corp. gets free advertising exposure and the computer manufacturer gets other considerations.

You could use an expression like:

"Would you like to establish a partnering relationship with us."

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not the answer I was looking for. Also you did not answer my initial question 'is it correct?'. I corrected my question to better explain the situation.